# karate framework - set header using variable as key

Tags: karate

I have a fairly simple feature file that is setting auth headers for an HTTP call, however I want the name of the header (i.e., the key) to be configurable per env.

My config looks like this:

```
    var config = { 
        apiKeyHeader: 'x-first-key',
        apiKey: 'someValue';
    }

    if (env == 'test') { 
        config.apiKeyHeader = 'x-other-key';
    }
```

Then in a feature file:

```
    Scenario: call with header key
      * print apiKeyHeader
      Given path '/myApi'
      And header apiKeyHeader = apiKey
      When method get
      Then status 200
```

Output from the test is something like this:

```
    14:00:00.123 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] x-first-key
    1 > GET http://localhost:8080/myApi
    1 > apiKeyHeader:  someValue
```

The variable is set correctly, however, in the header is set with the literal string `apiKeyHeader`. How can I make it use the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`headers`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#headers) and there are ways to [set a key for a JSON variable](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#eval).

```
* def headerKey = 'x-first-key',
* def headerData = {}
* headerData[headerKey] = 'someValue'
# url, etc
* headers headerData
```